# How to add 25 minutes in 2 hours

Tags: php

I am creating an application in which people book house removal. User can select number of hours like 2, 3 or 4 and system calculate  driving . I want to add driving time into selected time using php like 3 hours + 2 hours and 35 minutes.

How to do it?

I am not looking to add minutes in current time. I want to add 3 hours + 2 hours and 35 minutes.

Thanks,

Comment: And what is the problem? With which code are you stuck?

Comment: I dont know where to start thats why there is no code where I stuck. title of my question describe that I want to add some time in custom hours like 2, 4 etc

Comment: Convert both values to minutes and simply + add them together.

Comment: If I add them here is what I get. 
2 hours 35 minutes = 155 minutes
3 hours = 180 minutes  when adding 155 + 180 = 335 minutes
335 / 60 = 5.58 while it should be 5:35